# Rails where query with dates does not return boundary date data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql database using rails. it is working fine but it does not return the data which are near to boundary dates. for example

```
    if params[:from] and params[:to]
  fr = nil;
  fr = DateTime.parse(params[:from]) unless params[:from].empty?
  to = nil
  to = DateTime.parse(params[:to]) unless params[:to].empty?

  if !fr.nil? and !to.nil?
    puts "------------------"
    puts fr
    puts to
    @m = @m.where(start: fr..to)
  end
end
@m.size
```

Logs info

```
App 30303 stdout: ------------------
App 30303 stdout: 
App 30303 stdout: 2015-04-12T16:26:16+02:00
App 30303 stdout: 
App 30303 stdout: 2015-04-13T16:26:16+02:00
App 30303 stdout: 
App 30303 stdout: 0
```

I am sure that there is data for and hour before

```
 268129 | 2015-04-13 15:21:53 | 2015-04-13 15:21:53 |
```

where first is id, second column is start date

So for sure date are correct as I can see in logs and particular user has data also. I am trying to extract data from last 24 hours.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you please paste the output of `puts @m.to_sql` right before `@m.size`

Comment: SELECT `ms`.* FROM `ms`  WHERE `ms`.`user_id` = 127 AND (`ms`.`start` BETWEEN '2015-04-12 14:44:07' AND '2015-04-13 14:44:07')  ORDER BY `ms`....` aha i can see problem now it is 2 hour before but why is it so...as I provide right dates

Comment: time zone stuff, not sure if this would work but try replacing `DateTime.parse` with `Time.zone.parse`

Comment: no it is not working...;( thanks

Comment: but Now I have fixed the time zone issue as well, here is sql but did not working
SELECT `ms`.* FROM `ms`  WHERE `ms`.`user_id` = 127 AND (`ms`.`start` BETWEEN 'Sun, 12 Apr 2015 17:08:32' AND 'Mon, 13 Apr 2015 17:08:32')  ORDER BY `ms`.`created_at` DESC

Comment: what did you change ? rails is now sending the dates as strings instead of date objects

Comment: now.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'), I have used this to remove the timezone..

Answer (score 0):

ok so the problem is that the code uses a time zone while the database seems to hold a datetime object without timezone info, so we need to tell rails to take that time and assume it's normal utc time, hopefully this works.

```
if params[:from] && params[:to]
  Time.use_zone('UTC') do
    fr = Time.parse params[:from]
    to = Time.parse params[:to]
  end
  @m = @m.where(start: fr..to)
  end
end
@m.size
```